# Weird SqlCommand.Parameter behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Using Visual Studio 2010 Pro SP1 with .NET Framework 4 SP1.

I have this simple code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tatCAN_FMS", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = gsmData.CANSquarellMode.Value ? 2 : 1;
```

where `cmd` is a `SqlCommand` and `gsmData.CANSquarellMode.Value = true;`
`gsmData.CANSquarell` is `bool?` type.

When I debug this code using the default "Debug" configuration the value of `@tatCAN_FMS = 2`, the correct value.

But, If I debug the same code again using the default "Release" configuration, the value of `@tatCAN_FMS = NULL`. Why?

Is this a bug of somesort or I'm missing something?

EDIT1:

In default "Release" configuration, if I manually set

```
cmd.Parameters["@tatCAN_FMS2"] = gsmData.CANSquarellMode.Value ? 2 : 1;
```

using Immediate Window the Parameter value is set  to the expected value (2).

Comment: you said Release Configuration, but you are not showing what does the debug configuration look like...?

Comment: Do you have transformable Web.Config files (i.e. Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config)?  It might be that you have 2 different connection strings to 2 different databases.  The data or column type might be different in both databases?

Comment: Could `gsmData.CANSquarellMode` be `null` in your release configuration?

Comment: Using any conditional compilation symbols?

Comment: @Oded gsmData.CANSquarellMode always have value and always = true.

Comment: if always has and always true then it shouldn't error nothing is Always especially in the programming world..

Comment: @Reniuz I do not use conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: change your cmd.parameters.add with 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tatCAN_FMS", gsmData.CANSqaurellMode.Value ? 2 : 1); 
The Parameters.Add has been deprecated btw.. for starters

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload for Parameters.AddWithValue(string name, object value) which includes the value of the parameter, and put your gsmData.CANSquarellMode.Value ? 2 : 1 in there.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tatCAN_FMS", gsmData.CANSqaurellMode.Value ? 2 : 1);
```

[MS SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)

Comment: this worked! But still trying to understand why the other way does not work.

Comment: @RHaguiuda It is a strange behavior I have seen before. The Add command is supposed to return the SQLParameter that you added, so accessing the value should be fine... but it seems like when you do this you are getting a copy value instead of the value added to the collection. [MS SqlParameterCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht4eset1.aspx). I unfortunatly did not investigate further than that, since I got it working.